# "Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames" while using pipeline.fit()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

Code: I am using a different columns for my actual application but have created numeric_features and categorical feature in the same way as defined in the sklearn documentation (shown below).I am trying to fit transform   Numerical and Categorical variables using ColumnTransformer and then use this in the pipeline as shown above. When I try to fit (clf.fit) , I get the error shown below.
Thanks for the help in advance!

```
categorical_features = ['embarked', 'sex', 'pclass']
numeric_features = ['age', 'fare']
        numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
                ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
                ('scaler', StandardScaler())])
        
        categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
            ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
            ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])
       
     clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),('classifier', LogisticRegression())])
        
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
          
    
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)



**Error:**

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\new\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in _get_column_indices(X, key)
    424         try:
--> 425             all_columns = X.columns
    426         except AttributeError:

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-58e35cca456a> in <module>
      4 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
      5 
----> 6 clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

~\new\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    328         """
    329         fit_params_steps = self._check_fit_params(**fit_params)
--> 330         Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    331         with _print_elapsed_time('Pipeline',
    332                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):

~\new\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    290                 cloned_transformer = clone(transformer)
    291             # Fit or load from cache the current transformer
--> 292             X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
    293                 cloned_transformer, X, y, None,
    294                 message_clsname='Pipeline',

~\new\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    350 
    351     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 352         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    353 
    354     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

~\new\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    738     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    739         if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 740             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    741         else:
    742             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

~\new\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    527         self._validate_transformers()
    528         self._validate_column_callables(X)
--> 529         self._validate_remainder(X)
    530 
    531         result = self._fit_transform(X, y, _fit_transform_one)

~\new\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in _validate_remainder(self, X)
    325         cols = []
    326         for columns in self._columns:
--> 327             cols.extend(_get_column_indices(X, columns))
    328 
    329         remaining_idx = sorted(set(range(self._n_features)) - set(cols))

~\new\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in _get_column_indices(X, key)
    425             all_columns = X.columns
    426         except AttributeError:
--> 427             raise ValueError("Specifying the columns using strings is only "
    428                              "supported for pandas DataFrames")
    429         if isinstance(key, str):

ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames
```